# How to use the Nagios check_disk plugin with autofs?

Tags: nagios, network-attached-storage, hard-drive

I've been using `check_disk` without problems until yesterday to check the free space in some partitions.
Now we just added a NAS service from our hosting and I could mount it without problems, and, since we have a fixed amount of space, I would like to check the free space with Nagios for not being overcharged.

The problem is sometimes when `check_disk` goes to check then I get "unknown" status since of course [autofs](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/Linux-Dictionary/html/a.html) don't maintain the partition mounted 100% of the time. *[(Nagios-users) check_disk and autofs](http://www.mail-archive.com/nagios-users@lists.sourceforge.net/msg22709.html)* recommends making a wrapper for the plugin, but I don't feel comfortable with that.

Any idea about a better solution?

### Edit:

Well, I found a solution for this:

1. I've compiled and installed the [check_file](http://www.lnxsys.ca/software/check_file/) plugin.
2. Created a file on the NAS root: `.nagioscheck`.
3. Configured Nagios to check often if this file exists, rather than check the space.

So I can check if the NAS is mounted and the free space.

> SERVICE STATUS: OK file or directory /mnt/backup/.nagioscheck exists

Answer (score 2):

Why not make a static entry in fstab instead using automount so it is always mounted?

In the GNU df manual:

> This version of df cannot show the
>   space available on unmounted file
>   systems, because on most kinds of
>   systems doing so requires very
>   nonportable intimate knowledge of file
>   system structures.

So I would guess if GNU df is not going to show the free space of a partition that is not mounted, a Nagios plugin probably won't either.  But I could be wrong :-)

Maybe if you are using ext2/3 , by parsing out free blocks, block count, and block size out of tune2f you might be able to quickly write a plugin that will accomplish this:

```
sudo tune2fs -l /dev/sdb1
```

Answer (score 2):

Is there any way for the nagios server to query the NAS directly? That would be the most direct course of action.

Comment: Good point I think, a good NAS should have SNMP support.

Comment: Exactly. The disk usage should be monitored on the file server, not the clients.